# JQuery Ajax using post - is it blocking?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to make jQuery's `post` method wait for server side code to complete?

In my example below, `post` is not waiting for my `php` script to finish.  Though `php` is  calling `sleep(10)`, `post` returns right away, resulting in `javascript` clearing out the value in #temsg and changing the text of $sendmsg too early.

```
$('#sendmsg').click(function() {

    $("#sendmsg").html("sending....");

    var msg = $("#temsg").val();
    var to_id = 123;
    $.post("http://localhost:8888/ci/index.php/members/addMessage", 
        {message: msg, tomember: to_id}, 
           function(data){
               $("#temsg").val('');
               $("#sendmsg").html("Leave Message");
           },'json');

    $("#infomsg").show();
    $("#infomsg").html("Message Sent!");    
    setTimeout(function() { $("#infomsg").hide('slow'); }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is (supposed to be) *asynchronous* - that means that the `$.post()` method is non-blocking and returns immediately and the rest of your function continues executing, and then eventually when a response comes back the `success` handler is called.

You can make the JS code pause until the Ajax request returns by doing a *synchronous* (blocking) request, but given that (most) browsers run JavaScript on the same thread as the UI that means the browser will not respond to anything until the response comes back which is horrible for the user - essentially the browser would be locked up for the ten seconds that your server-side code is sleeping.

The solution is to stick with the default *asynchronous* request but move the code from after your `$.post()` call into the success handler:

```
$('#sendmsg').click(function() {

    $("#sendmsg").html("sending....");

    var msg = $("#temsg").val();
    var to_id = 123;
    $.post("http://localhost:8888/ci/index.php/members/addMessage", 
           {message: msg, tomember: to_id}, 
           function(data){
               $("#temsg").val('');
               $("#sendmsg").html("Leave Message");
               $("#infomsg").show();
               $("#infomsg").html("Message Sent!");    
               setTimeout(function() { $("#infomsg").hide('slow'); }, 3000);
           },'json');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is **asynchronous**. The fact the code keeps running doesn't mean the sleep didn't occur.

That thread on the server "sleeps" , while `javascript` continue executing the next lines.

---

Example how to use `async:false`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8888/ci/index.php/members/addMessage",
  async: false,
  data: {message: msg, tomember: to_id},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
               $("#temsg").val('');
               $("#sendmsg").html("Leave Message");
           }
});
```

`ajax` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I can see that sleep did occur (using firebug; the http call takes 10+ seconds).. Is there a way to make the jquery post wait until the php script has had time to process all input? For example; if there was an error; I would like to send that back to the JS